# Problems with implementing exceptions in Java

Tags: java, exception, char, int, try-catch

I want to write a program which converts a binary number in a decimal.
Ive found out that the problem is that I cant even get the "catch path".
I also know that I have to change somthing with the char but I absolutely dont get a working solution. Thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BinaryStringToNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String inputBinaer;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Type in a binary number: ");
        inputBinaer = input.next();
        input.close();

        try
          {
            convert(inputBinaer);
          }
          catch (NumberFormatException e)
          {
            System.out.println( "Just numbers!" );
          } finally {
            System.out.println( "Finally" );
          }
    }

    public static void convert(String inputBinaer) throws NumberFormatException{

        char [] puffer;
        int dez = 0;

        puffer = inputBinaer.toCharArray();

        for(int i=0;i<puffer.length;i++){
                if(puffer[i]== '1'){
             dez = (int) (dez + Math.pow(2, puffer.length-1-i));
             }
            }

        System.out.println("The decimal number is: " + dez);

    }

}
```

Comment: Your `convert` method will never throw `NumberFormatException`. Why don't you throw it?

Comment: Didnt I do that behind the convert method? What do I have to do to get a NumberFormatException? Ive been trying for hours now.

Comment: And where exactly in `convert` do you believe the exception will be thrown? Help us at least understand your expectations.

Comment: since acceptable answers were given here's a small hint, use this `dez += Math.pow(2, puffer.length-1-i));` instead of `dez = (int) (dez + Math.pow(2, puffer.length-1-i));`, it's less pain to eyes(IMHO), don't worry the compiler will get it right

Answer (score 2):

To get to the `catch` block, an exception has to be thrown somewhere. Normally, the Java methods do this for you, but since you are parsing everything yourself, you will have to throw the exception. One way would be to add a `throw` statement to the `convert()` method whenever it encounters an invalid digit:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BinaryStringToNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String inputBinaer;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Type in a binary number: ");
        inputBinaer = input.next();
        input.close();

        try
          {
            convert(inputBinaer);
          }
          catch (NumberFormatException e)
          {
            System.out.println( "Just numbers!" );
          } finally {
            System.out.println( "Finally" );
          }
    }

    public static void convert(String inputBinaer) throws NumberFormatException{

        char [] puffer;
        int dez = 0;

        puffer = inputBinaer.toCharArray();

        for(int i=0;i<puffer.length;i++){
                if(puffer[i]== '1'){
             dez = (int) (dez + Math.pow(2, puffer.length-1-i));
             } else if (puffer[i] != '0') {
                     throw new NumberFormatException("Invalid digit: " + puffer[i]);
             }
            }

        System.out.println("The decimal number is: " + dez);

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works! I think Ive got it now. I will read some more articles.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify where do you throw the NumberFormatException. I'd put an if in the for loop where I'd check the char, and if it was not a '0' or a '1', I'd throw an exception. Hope I helped.

Answer (score -1):

You can throw `NumberFormatException` in case of bad input. That is allowed in Java.